Calculate the duration in weeks that it would take to lose a specified amount of body weight (BW) givent 1% of body weight is lost exactly each week?
Calculate the duration in weeks that it would take to lose a specified amount of body weight (BW), in pounds, given that 1% of body weight is lost exactly each week?
I would like to be able to find this in googlesheets using one formula where it takes an input of desired weight loss and outputs weeks to achieve the weight loss given that 1% of body weight is lost each week.
This means that once the starting weight is known, the 1% weight loss must be recalculated each week such that 1% is calculated based on the new current lower weight.
For the google sheet shown:
A2 = The starting weight of a person that would be typed in manually.
A4 = The desired weight loss of a person that would be typed in manually.
D2 = The formula that will iteratively calculate the time in weeks it would take to lose 1% of body weight per week given that the person is starting at 200 lbs body weight (A2) and would like to lose 20 lbs of body weight (A4)
In I1 through K12, ive shown the manual iterative process that finds how many weeks it would take for the 200 pound person to lose 20 pounds.
By hand what this is doing is the following.  Take current weight, find what 1% reduction of weight is, and subtract that 1% reduction from the current weight to get the new weight for the new week.  Continue this process until the minimum 20 pound weight reduction is seen and then look at the time value in weeks to know how many weeks it took.
The answer then should be 11 weeks.
How can this be done in one single formula that would output in cell D2?
I appreciate any help received.
My only solution to this currently given that I dont want to see the manual process is to put the manual iterative process in a different sheet (say sheet 2) and then sheet 1 would only ask for the two inputs and give the output. I would just need to make sure the manual iterative calculations span enough time in weeks to ensure all possible desired weight loss possibilities will be accounted for.


To calculate the number of weeks required, use pduration(), like this:
=pduration(1%, A2, A2 - A4)

The result will be a negative decimal number like -10.58864446 because we are going down in weight. To get a positive integer number of weeks, add round(abs()), like this:
=roundup(abs(pduration(1%, A2, A2 - A4)))


See pduration().

Perfect! I didnt even think about finance equations but this did exactly what I needed. It even allows for greater precision.  Thank you

Nice, I looked for a function but must have missed that one.  FYI, you can get a positive result simply by flipping the values rather than adding ABS: =PDURATION(1%, A2-A4, A2)

@Blindspots yes... but I think it usually makes sense to set present_value to the present value and future_value to the future value, for consistency. This is not my favorite among Google Sheets functions but it works for some use cases.

SUMPRODUCT
=SUMPRODUCT(starting_weight*99%^SEQUENCE(50)>target_weight)+1

For example:
=SUMPRODUCT(A2*99%^SEQUENCE(50)>A2-A4)+1

SEQUENCE  SUMPRODUCT
Explanation

The formula for compounding is amt*rate^periods

amt is the starting_weight
rate is 99% (or 0.99 / -1%)
periods is the number of weeks.


A number SEQUENCE is used for the periods so that the result is an array of values over many weeks. 50 is used but this can likely be  reduced
That array of decreasing weights is compared to the target_weight to see if the array values are larger which returns an array of TRUE and FALSE.
SUMPRODUCT adds that array interpreting TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0 and the result represents the number of weeks where the weight was higher than the target_weight.
1 is added to that result  because it is one more week before the weight is equal to or less than the target.


Thank you! This technically gives the answer as well but one must be aware of how much of a sequence one should use to ensure an incorrect solution is not provided.  Honestly if a sequence of 100 was used, it'd work for all cases.  That said, the solution using pduration offered a simple way of getting the result without the additional moving part of sequence. I still learned a lot from this. I appreciate your time

Np. I learnt something too. I wasn't familiar with pduration.
